# Proper Handling of *NOT* Choosing a Select Option

Tags: docusignapi

We're developing a project at our company that displays a company roster and allows easy DocuSign paperwork generation with many of the tabs already filled out so that we can cut down on inaccuracy and increase ease of use.

With the REST API, I am able to generate envelopes just fine with templates inside and even fill out some of the tabs for the recipient (the tabs we have information for) with information from our database.

The problem I'm experiencing lies with the list tabs (`select` drop-down boxes) on the templates. When an envelope is generated *from the DocuSign website itself*,  the select boxes have "-- select --" selected, and I see that on the template editor as well, which is proper because we need the employee or manager to select those things (they're required). However, using the API and **not even touching the `listTabs` when doing a `PUT` for the recipient tabs**, there is no "-- select --" even on the drop-down and the first option on the list tab is pre-selected.

We're still using the DocuSign website (via "Review Documents" in email or simply opening the user's inbox on the website) to fill out the paperwork; the generation is the only thing we do with the API at the moment. This list tab thing is a problem; if someone skips selecting those list tabs, then there's already a pre-selected value that could be wrong. Even when the tab is marked as required, the template sees that there is a value selected and it passes validation. Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong with the template or API calls here or is this a bug?

I would provide code, but it's scattered across so many Java classes that it would be hard to compile into something easily understood on a stackoverflow question. Not only that, but, as I said, I'm not even touching the listTabs at all when doing a `PUT` on the recipient tabs.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'll try to do some tests on this and see what I come up with.  Could be a bug with the api, or maybe we need to do something special

Comment: Just had a question (I commented on your answer) before I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I believe this is by design, and if you want the "default select item" in there you just have to add it in.  I would imagine that some people do not want a "null" option so the api gives them complete control over the list items, whereas when you send through the console it seems to always have "--select--" as the first option.

When you send through the console the "--select" option has a check mark next to it, which means it's just another list option.  I was able to mimic this with the following request body:

```
{
"emailBlurb": "This goes in the email body",
"emailSubject": "API Signature Request",
"documents": [
    {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "document.pdf"
    }
],
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "<email_address_goes_here>",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "250",
                        "yPosition": "75",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "listTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "100",
                        "yPosition": "90",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "tabLabel": "DropDownList",
                        "listItems": [
                            {
                                "selected": "false",
                                "text": "--select--",
                                "value": "--select--"
                            },
                            {
                                "selected": "false",
                                "text": "One",
                                "value": "One"
                            },
                            {
                                "selected": "false",
                                "text": "Two",
                                "value": "Two"
                            },
                            {
                                "selected": "false",
                                "text": "Three",
                                "value": "Three"
                            }
                        ],
                        "width": "56"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
"status": "sent"
```

}

Comment: So, a question then: Should I manually add in the `--select--` list item on the template definition and, if so, does the `--select--` value still validate as a valid choice or is it excluded from valid values, making the field look like it's not filled out if that option is selected? I'm searching for a way to have nothing at all selected when the document is opened, requiring them to select something to continue without having to write code to mess with the `listTabs` at all.

Comment: Yes add it to your template.  When I test the code that I posted above, once you open the envelope it starts on --select-- but it does not allow you complete the signing without selecting one of the other options, which is how the Console acts so I think you're good go.

Comment: This is so strange, but I went in to test the effect of your recommendations on one of our templates, changed one of the list tabs as recommended, and re-generated the envelope. Now it's not happening to any of the templates at all, regardless of my changes. Maybe the behavior was altered or something, but you're a savior as always Ergin! Thanks!